# how to send json object from REST client using javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a POJO given below which I want to PUT to the server as JSON or XML.

This is what I have done

**CLIENT:**

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());

public void putFriend(String uri , Friend friend)
{
    System.out.println(friend.toString());

    target = target.path(some_path).path(uri);
    ClientResponse response =        target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(Entity.entity(friend,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),ClientResponse.class);
}
```

Examples I found on web were using WebResource.

I don't know how to do using WebTarget. What I have done is taken from some example found on SO but Entity.entity() gives error undefined method entity(friend, String).

**POJO**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Friend{

    private String friendURI;
    private String event;
    private String uri;

    String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }
    void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
    String getFriendURI() {
        return friendURI;
    }
    void setFriendURI(String friendURI) {
        this.friendURI = friendURI;
    }
    String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
public String toString() {
        return "Friend [friendURI=" + friendURI + ", uri=" + uri + ", event=" + event
                 + "]";
}
```

Please guide how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two different Jersey major versions, 1.x and 2.x, You seems to be trying to use a combination of both, which won't work. The 2.x versions don't have some classes as in 1.x and vice versa.

If you want to use Jersey 2.x, then you should be using [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), rather than `ClientResponse`

```
Response response = target.request().put(Entity.json(friend));
                                        // .json == automatic 'application/json'
```

- See [Working with the Client API for 2.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)
- Also as mentioned in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27181507/2587435), the getters and setters should be public for the `Friend` class
- Also see the [`WebTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) API

Basic breakdown.

- Calling `request()` on `WebTarget` returns an [`Invocation.Buidler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

  ```
  Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
  ```
- Once we call [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#put%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity%29), we get back a `Response`

  ```
  Response response = builder.put(Entity.json(friend));
  ```
- To extract a known type from the response, we could use `readEntity(Class type)`

  ```
  String responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);
  response.close();
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me every time. Entity.json(friend) gives error that method not define json(friend).

Comment: Make sure `Entity` is [`javax.ws.rs.client.Entity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html)

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong Entity class was imported. Corrected that. Thanks. And yes getters and setters are public. Just copied the code from older post.

Comment: One more thing, you explain really well. Thumbs up for that. Do you have any blog or website? It would be really helpful for newbies. Otherwise I guess I know who to meet :).

Comment: Thank you very much peeskillet. Could you also show the example where you could use the access token as header in the request after getting it from the Oauth2 process and do the post request for login?

Comment: For simple, key value pair, we can use Map and use Entity.json(mapObj).

Comment: I have a API which is developed in spring boot , I am trying to hit that API, and I have passed my POJO object in the Entity.json , but it is not getting mapped with Object there in the API. I am getting 400 from my API , which I send when the parameters are not present. What might be the issue.

Comment: @SalmanShaikh Please post another question on SO. I cannot tell without seeing some code.

Comment: `String responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);
response.close();` : this line save me

Comment: Yes I have imported  javax.ws.rs.client.Entity and its worked, Thanks dude