# Upgrading from Jersey Client 1.x to Jersey Client 2.x

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am using `jersey-client-1.9`. sample code:

```java
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Client client = Client.create();
webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8047/storage/hive.json");
String input = //rest request
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
String queryRespose = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

As this project has changed from `com.sun.jersey.api.client` to `org.glassfish.jersey.client`. How to achieve this in `jersey-client-2.8` ?

**Edit:**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8047/query.json");
String input =//rest request
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.json(input));
String queryRespose = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

This worked...:)

Comment: I don't know why there is anything related to `com.sun.jersey` in the exception message. You need to get rid of anything Jersey 1.x (`com.sun.jersey`) related if you're going to use Jersey 2.x (`org.glassfish.jersey`)

Comment: @peeskillet my bad.. I had both 1.9 & 2.8 jars in my project. I removed 1.9. Now everything working fine...Thanks..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Jersey 2.x, you can build the `Client` with `ClientBuilder`

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

In Jersey 2.x `WebTarget` is analogous to Jersey 1.x `WebResource`, and instead of calling `client.resource()` to get the `WebResource`, you call `client.target()` to get the `WebTarget`

```
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
```

Then you need to call `request()` on the `WebTarget` to get an [`Invocation.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html), which will allow you to chain other calls

```
Invocation.Builder invocation = target.request();
```

To send an entity, we need to pass an [`Entity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) to one of the `Invocation.Builder`'s request method. For instance

```
Response response = builder.post(Entity.json(input);
```

To read the response, use `response.readEntity(String.class)`. So altogether, you can do

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.json(input));
String entity = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

**See Also:**

- [how to send json object from REST client using javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27211173/2587435)
- [Client API documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html)

---

### UPDATE

You may also need the following dependency for JSON/POJO support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the `JacksonFeature` with the client. This is so `input` (if you want to use a POJO instead of String) can be serialized to JSON

```
client.register(JacksonFeature.class);
```